# Firebase firestore & Express - build json getting nested documents

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So far I am building an app using express and firebase cloud functions. I am not able to create a nested json according to this db:

[image: firestore db]

Here is the code:

```
exports.tstMenu = (req, res) => {
    let shop = db.collection('shops').doc(req.params.name).collection('menus');
    shop.get()
    .then((data) => {
        let menu = [];
        data.forEach((doc) => {
            let categories = getCategories(doc.id, shop);
            menu.push({
                menuID: doc.id,
                name: doc.data().name,
                position: doc.data().position,
                categories: categories,
            });
            console.log(menu);
        });
        return res.json(menu);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message});
    });
}

function getCategories(id, db){
    let shop = db.doc(id).collection('categories');
    return shop.get()
    .then((data) => {
        let categs = [];
        data.forEach((doc) => {
            var menuElements = [];//getMenuElement(doc.id, shop);
            categs.push({
                catID: doc.id,
                name: doc.data().name,
                position: doc.data().position,
                menuElements: menuElements,
            });
        });
        return categs;
    });
}
```

and the result of `tstMenu` is:

[image: json web]

while the log is showing this:

[image: log]

Can anyone explain me how to fix it? I am quite sure that promises are not received when `tstMenu` reaches `return res.json(menu);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies within this line :

```
let categories = getCategories(doc.id, shop);
```

`getCategories` is an async method. It returns a promise so you can't use it directly as you do.

You either should do your assignment in a `then` callback or you should use `async await`.

```
exports.tstMenu = (req, res) => {
    let shop = db.collection('shops').doc(req.params.name).collection('menus');
    shop.get()
    .then((data) => {
     let menu = [];
     const promises = data.docs.map((doc) =>  // change this from forEach to map
            getCategories(doc.id, shop).then(categories =>{
               menu.push({
                menuID: doc.id,
                name: doc.data().name,
                position: doc.data().position,
                categories: categories,
            });
        );

     return Promise.all(promises).then(()=> res.json(menu)); // return res after all promises completed
       
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message});
    });
}
```

Or

```
exports.tstMenu = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let shop = db.collection('shops').doc(req.params.name).collection('menus');
    const data = await shop.get()
    let menu = [];
     const promises = data.docs.map((doc) =>  // change this from forEach to map
            getCategories(doc.id, shop).then(categories =>{
               menu.push({
                menuID: doc.id,
                name: doc.data().name,
                position: doc.data().position,
                categories: categories,
            });
        );

    await  Promise.all(promises);
    return res.json(menu)
  } catch(err) { 
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message});
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, I have tried but now nothing is displayed and `console.log(menu)` inside `then(categories..)` shows 4 empty arrays `[] [] [] []`

Comment: Can this be done even with a third function? including a third call and promise to get menuElements data?

Comment: @Dennis you can chain any numbers of calls if you track what returns a `Promise` what should be awaited. If you going to call `getMenuElements` function in `forEach` block you also will need to modify your `getCategories` method like above.

Comment: Just tried, got this error:

 `>  C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe - firebase  serve[260196]: c:\ws\src\node_http2.cc:893: Assertion (flags_ & SESSION_STATE_READING_STOPPED) != (0)' failed.
>   1: 002006CE node::MakeCallback+3982`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222768/discussion-between-eldar-and-dennis).